# Python 3.5 - Checking if a variable is the same as in a file

Tags: python, file

I have a script that asks the user if they want to enter a previously used username or create a new one. I've got it to store the username in a file if the user wants to create a new one, but how would I make it check if a previously used username is in the file?

Eg:
User enters a previously used username
Python checks the username list in a file for the entered username
if the username entered is in the list, it will let them continue
if not, it asks them to either re enter the username or create a new one

*Also*
if anyone could also tell me how to make it so when a username is entered, it doesn't write over the previous entered username, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I make it check if a previously used username is in the file?

Read the file and see if the inputted username exists:

```
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    if inputted_username in [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]: # getting rid of '\n'
        # rest of code
```

> how to make it so when a username is entered, it doesn't write over the previous entered username

Open the file with the append flag:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'a') as f:
    # rest of code
```

Comment: Great help, but using the append just writes the new username onto the end of the previous one. Any way to make it start a new line each time?

Comment: When writing a new name to the file, append '\n' to the end: `f.write(inputted_username + '\n')`